# Apprication launch error: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, metadata, jupyter, python-importlib

I have problem with starting my jupyter notebook after uninstalling and updating of sklearn library
as below.

```
conda uninstall scikit-learn --yes
conda install scikit-learn==0.23.1
```

I can not start my jupyter notebook from ANACONDA NAGIGATOR by clicking the jupyter notebook launch button.
The Application launch error says,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 31, in 
from importlib import metadata
ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib' (D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 85, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in 
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in 
from .json_compat import get_current_validator, ValidationError
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\json_compat.py", line 10, in 
import jsonschema
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 33, in 
import importlib_metadata as metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'
```

Dose anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does it say if you type "conda list anaconda" into the shell?